# How do you add exclude flags to Python git

Tags: python, git

Using the `git` method from the `sh` package in Python, I am trying to craft the following git statement:

```
git grep -i -e "(example1|example2)" -- './*' ':!*.java' ':!*.xml' HEAD
```

In my code, I am using the following:

```
exclude_list = '-- \'./*\' \':!*.java\' \':!*.xml\''

result = git('grep', '-i', '-e', '"({})"'.format(r'\|'.join(self.keywords)), exclude_list, 'HEAD', _tty_out=False))
```

Which when I run returns the following error:

```
Error:

  RAN: /usr/bin/git grep -i -e "(example1\|example2)" -- './*' ':!*.java' ':!*.xml' HEAD

  STDOUT:


  STDERR:
error: unknown option ` './*' ':!*.java' ':!*.xml''
usage: git grep [<options>] [-e] <pattern> [<rev>...] [[--] <path>...]
```

However, if I run the command locally, it returns as expected. I am not a Python dev, unfortunately, so not sure what I am doing wrong!

Comment: `'"({})"'.format(r'\|'.join(self.keywords))` remove the backslash. It's generating `"(example1\|example2)"` instead of `"(example1|example2)"`

Comment: That doesn't fix the issue @TinNguyen, you can escape the pipe in the regex with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

You pass `'grep', '-i', '-e',`  as separate parameters but you pass `exclude_list` as a single string; `git` complains about not understanding this single string. Split it:

```
result = git('grep', '-i', '-e', '"({})"'.format(r'\|'.join(self.keywords)), '--', './*', ':!*.java', ':!*.xml', 'HEAD', _tty_out=False))
```

This is the essential part: `'--', './*', ':!*.java', ':!*.xml',`

Comment: Thanks, that still returns an error though and unfortunately printing the exception shows nothing in STDERR to say what the problem is. Any idea? The git ommand that run is correct now